# extjs - no scrollbar on window resize despite overflowing content available

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, overflow

The following is the layout we use for our extjs app.
I have meager knowledge on Extjs yet have a good knowledge in JS.

```
Ext.define('WebApp.view.Viewport', {
    extend : 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires : [
        'WebApp.view.navigation.TasksMenu',
        'WebApp.view.navigation.TreemenuView',
        'WebApp.view.navigation.WorkspaceView'
    ],
    layout : 'border',
    id: 'Viewport',
    items : [{
            region : 'north',
            xtype : 'TopMenu'
        }, {
            region : 'west',
            xtype : 'LeftMenu'
        }, {
            region : 'center',
            xtype : 'userarea'
        }
    ]
});
```

When ever i resize the window there are no scroll bars even though there are overflowing content in the body tag.
While inspecting the body tag I can see that the width of the body tag is getting altered each time I resize the window.
If the window width becomes 1000px after resize then the body tag width is changed to 1000px. 
I do not want the body tag to increase or decrease in width/height when ever I resize the window.

I altered the css with !important and with min-width properties but it did not work.
It seems that ExtJs is dynamically altering the width and height on resize.

How do i overcome this?

Comment: Can you please try including `Ext.getBody().setStyle('overflow', 'auto');` at the top of your code? (as the firstline)

Comment: That's the way the `border` layout works. You can add `scrollable: true` to any of the regions or use a different layout.